# throttle Spark Structured Streaming throughput

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, rate-limiting

I need to batch process large files, and call an http endpoint for every row in the final DataFrame. The endpoint can only handle a limited, relatively low throughput (lets say 100TPS).

How can I rate limit `DataFrameWriter#foreach` to avoid overwhelming the endpoint?

I was thinking, if I can break up the initial file into many small micro batches of let's say 100 rows each, then I can do this with Trigger windowing, but I don't know how to break up a microbatch either.